# Macvim subtle comment keywords

Tags: vim, macvim

[image]

Comments keyword are damn highlighted in Macvim/terminal vim and keeps on irritating me. I am not a pro in customizing vim, but really want to get rid of them and have subtle grey keywords

Answer (score 2):

You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can investigate where it comes from; (the last lines of) `:scriptnames` may help.

One solution in your case would be *linking* the syntax groups to the original `Comment` group, so that the distinction is lost. This can be done in `~/.vimrc`:

```
:hi link FoundSyntaxGroupHere Comment
```

Answer (score 0):

Comments were highlighted because of [vim javascript plugin](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) and by setting following inside `.vimrc` file, i am able to stop my comments from getting highlighted

```
let g:javascript_ignore_javaScriptdoc="1
```